# How to make the association work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sites
end

class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups
end
```

I can get all groups which belongs to site:

```
Site.find(1).groups
```

But I can not get site to which belongs given group:

```
$ Group.find(1)
#<Group id:1 ...., site_id: "1">
$ Group.find(1).sites
nil
```

Why?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `belongs_to :site`?

Comment: Yes, thank you. Can you create the answer and I will close answer?

Comment: Tick off Atzoya. No need to have answers with same content and I'll survive not having received the 15pt. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because the group belongs to 1 it should be in singular form

```
$ Group.find(1).site
```

And also as Marcel Jackwerth said the belongs_to should also be in singular form

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :site
end
```

Comment: irb(main):015:0> Group.find(1).site
NoMethodError: undefined method `site' for #<Group:0x2bd3f10>

Comment: But it will be usefull with Marcel's comment.

Answer (score -1):

If it doesn't work you can always just add the following public method to group.rb

```
def site
  Site.find self.site_id
end
```